# A Music player that lets you sort albums by their year?

Tags: software-recommendation, music, music-player

Are there any music/audio players that let you sort the albums by the year? So for example:

[image]

Sort the albums seen in this view by the year. Oldest first or newest?

In short the lack of sorting in any of the Music players that I am aware of have this feature.

Bonus points as well if it lets me view the album art view.

Answer (score 3):

Most music players let you sort your music library by the album year if that was included in the meta-tags of your files.

Often it is only a setting to be made in the application's preferences. For **Rhythmbox** the menu *Edit > Preferences > General Tab* will open below box for ticking "Year" to add a "Year" (or any other choice) column to the library browser window:

[image]

---

My favorite player **Guayadeque** will open the menu to define columns for sorting on right click on the top bar of the library window:

[image]

With Guayadeque you can also sort the album view ascending or descending by year:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much. Now I will try to address the album art view :)

Comment: Interesting, so there is no way to always first order by track and then by year. I would like the newest albums at the top, then of course the albums to be in order also :D I have updated the question to make it more relevant also.

Comment: @JamieHutber I dunno about Rhythmbox but Guayadeque is quite versatile. I update my answer with a shot from album view sorted by year.

Comment: Fantastic, I will try it now :D